# Thomas Merton quote

Tags: quote

> We are so obsessed with doing that we have no time and no imagination left for being. As a result, men are valued not for what they are but for what they do or what they have—for their usefulness. ~Thomas Merton

I know what people do: they are doctors, lawyers, they play the piano very well, they run marathons, they are drunkards, slackers, artists, day dreamers. Eventually what counts is  the walk not the talk.

You may say someone is good natured or cruel but how would you know if you didn't witness him helping his fellowman or abusing him.

Thomas Merton seems not to value people for what they do, but for something else. But what else could they be?

Comment: All of the above?

Comment: Tomas Merton being a Trappist Monk, he is expected to believe that God knows what a man is just because He knows everything. So, keeping the context of the quote let's us understand it better. There is also the idea buried in there of what we can do to help others be that which he wants to hold up as valuable.  So, even if you disagree with the xtian ideals, you can be aware of them and have some understanding of them.

Comment: Utility is what remains after all that I (we?) cherish is gone.

Comment: Is doing not being?